# google drive hosting after browser got 404 error

Tags: html, web-services, twitter-bootstrap-3, hosting

I have create a new website using bootstrap.

I want to host it in googledrive.

I have upload my project folder in googledrive. then share option change to public. i have copy to the folder id

now browser ip googledrive.com/host/folder_id/index.html

But browser was showing

> **404 error** 
>   The requested URL /host/0B8EDhQEMaanYcnF2T2JEUGRQdWc was not found on this server.

Please some one help me how to host it on googledrive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working